# Make a Link From Database Text in ASP.NET MVC Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Hi I want to href this code so all the links are clickable:

```
<td>@item.Link</td>
```

How do I use the href here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do the job for you:

```
<td><a href="@item.Link">My Href</a></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want to use this value as the href value for your anchor, you may use the following as an example:

```
<td><a href="@item.Link">YOUR_LINK_TEXT</a></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [ActionLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) helper

```
@Html.ActionLink("<td>" + item.Link + "</td>", "myaction", "mycontroller")
```